# Defending against Walkers

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

In Episode 12 of Season 5 of The Walking Dead, the group arrives at

> the Alexandria Safe Zone, and meet Deanna Monroe and the others living inside.

How long have these survivors lived there? Did they build the wall before the walkers reached this area?

(My first question. Please advise if I can do better)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the TV show, the Alexandria community was a planned community which the military had designated as a safe-zone and told people to wait in. The expectation was that help and reinforcements would arrive later, but they never did.

Deanna's husband was an architect who helped design and plan the walls. Precisely when this happened is unclear. We don't know exactly when the community was started, but being that the military was still functioning, involved and thinking (or at least promising) that there would be reinforcements to send, it would stand to reason that it was in the very early days of the outbreak.

In the comics, the community was started by a man named Davidson. In this version, he was the one who began construction on the walls. Davidson was later forced to leave the safe-zone.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jirya - I would add that Deanna says she was on her way from DC to her district (she was a congresswoman; I think her district was in Ohio if I'm not mistaken) to help her constituents deal with the outbreak when the military stopped her and told her to go to the Safe Zone instead.  It is clear that this must have been very early in the outbreak.  She also says Washington was totally evacuated, which meant very few zombies were in the area (no people = no zombies, and Alexandria is literally yards away from the southernmost tip of Washington DC)